# How to remove blank lines from a Unix file

Tags: unix, awk, blank-line

I need to remove all the blank lines from an input file and write into an output file. Here is my data as below.

```
11216,33,1032747,64310,1,0,0,1.878,0,0,0,1,1,1.087,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,000603221321

11216,33,1033196,31300,1,0,0,1.5391,0,0,0,1,1,1.054,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,059762153003

11216,33,1033246,31300,1,0,0,1.5391,0,0,0,1,1,1.054,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,000603211032

11216,33,1033280,31118,1,0,0,1.5513,0,0,0,1,1,1.115,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,055111034001

11216,33,1033287,31118,1,0,0,1.5513,0,0,0,1,1,1.115,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,000378689701

11216,33,1033358,31118,1,0,0,1.5513,0,0,0,1,1,1.115,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,000093737301

11216,33,1035476,37340,1,0,0,1.7046,0,0,0,1,1,1.123,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,045802041926

11216,33,1035476,37340,1,0,0,1.7046,0,0,0,1,1,1.123,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,045802041954

11216,33,1035476,37340,1,0,0,1.7046,0,0,0,1,1,1.123,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,045802049326

11216,33,1035476,37340,1,0,0,1.7046,0,0,0,1,1,1.123,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,045802049383

11216,33,1036985,15151,1,0,0,1.4436,0,0,0,1,1,1.065,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,000093415580

11216,33,1037003,15151,1,0,0,1.4436,0,0,0,1,1,1.065,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,000781202001

11216,33,1037003,15151,1,0,0,1.4436,0,0,0,1,1,1.065,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,000781261305

11216,33,1037003,15151,1,0,0,1.4436,0,0,0,1,1,1.065,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,000781603955

11216,33,1037003,15151,1,0,0,1.4436,0,0,0,1,1,1.065,5,1,1,18-JAN-13,000781615746
```

Comment: This is my sample data and any of the below commands dont work for me. :(

Comment: They didn't work **because you asked the wrong question**. Did you actually try `sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' foo`?  Because if that didn't work then you need to restate the problem

Comment: @SOaddict, I see multiple answers here that answer your original question as well as ones that handle whitespace in the "blank" lines. If those don't work, I think you need to examine your input file and update the question.

Comment: I copy pasted the exact input file sample.

Comment: check this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/deleting-empty-lines-from-file.html

Comment: One possible reason why the commands below, which should work, seemed not to work is that the file originated on Windows or transited via a Windows machine and actually has CRLF (carriage return, line feed) endings instead of Unix-style NL (newline, aka LF) line endings.  Unix tools treat the CR as just another character, and therefore regexes like `/^$/` would fail to match a blank line with a CRLF ending.  The version using `sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d;s/[[:space:]]*$//'` should work for CRLF lines, too; the `/^[[:space:]]*$/` pattern matches a CR in the line.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
sed -i '/^$/d' foo
```

This tells `sed` to delete every line matching the regex `^$` i.e. every empty line. The `-i` flag edits the file in-place, if your `sed` doesn't support that you can write the output to a temporary file and replace the original:

```
sed '/^$/d' foo > foo.tmp
mv foo.tmp foo
```

If you also want to remove lines consisting only of whitespace (not just empty lines) then use:

```
sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' foo
```

**Edit:** also remove whitespace at the end of lines, because apparently you've decided you need that too:

```
sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d;s/[[:space:]]*$//' foo
```

Comment: I considered that possibility so wrote the "if your sed doesn't support that" part. Seems like at least seven people have wasted their time trying to help you and you either aren't reading or aren't thinking properly.

Comment: Error msg: sed: illegal option -- i
Usage: sed [-n] [-e script] [-f source_file] [file...]

Comment: so you were doing it wrong for 19 hours by not reading properly or not using copy'n'paste properly? sheesh

Comment: It was my bad Jonathan.Your answer was right. Didn't check it again from yesterday.

Comment: anyone who has trouble with the -i option on a Mac: use `-i .bak` instead (as in `sed -i .bak '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' foo`. The version of sed we have wants a file extension to use when doing in-place edits. So passing `-i .bak` tells it to copy the existing file with an extension of `.bak` that you can restore incase the in-place edit fails.

Comment: Note that the `-i` option in GNU `sed` also accepts a backup suffix as an optional argument, so if you write `-i.bak` with the option and argument touching, the code will work with both BSD (Mac OS X) `sed` and GNU `sed`.  Mac OS X requires the backup suffix and allows it to be separate from the `-i` option.  Standards: such wonderful things…

Answer (score 45):

```
awk 'NF' filename
```

```
awk 'NF > 0' filename
```

```
sed -i '/^$/d' filename
```

```
awk '!/^$/' filename
```

```
awk '/./' filename
```

The NF also removes lines containing only blanks or tabs, the regex `/^$/` does not.

Comment: In case someone have confusion > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544804/how-awk-nf-filename-is-working

Answer (score 17):

Use [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) to match any line that has nothing between the start anchor (`^`) and the end anchor (`$`):

```
grep -v '^$' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

If you want to remove lines with only whitespace, you can still use grep. I am using Perl regular expressions in this example, but here are other ways:

```
grep -P -v '^\s*$' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

or, without Perl regular expressions:

```
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: Still I get whitespaces in my op file.

Answer (score 12):

```
sed -e '/^ *$/d' input > output
```

Deletes all lines which consist only of blanks (or is completely empty).  You can change the blank to `[ \t]` where the `\t` is a representation for tab.  Whether your shell or your `sed` will do the expansion varies, but you can probably type the tab character directly.  And if you're using GNU or BSD `sed`, you can do the edit in-place, if that's what you want, with the `-i` option.

---

> If I execute the above command still I have blank lines in my output file. What could be the reason?

There could be several reasons.  It might be that you don't have blank lines but you have lots of spaces at the end of a line so it looks like you have blank lines when you cat the file to the screen.  If that's the problem, then:

```
sed -e 's/  *$//' -e '/^ *$/d' input > output
```

The new regex removes repeated blanks at the end of the line; see previous discussion for blanks or tabs.

Another possibility is that your data file came from Windows and has CRLF line endings.  Unix sees the carriage return at the end of the line; it isn't a blank, so the line is not removed.  There are multiple ways to deal with that.  A reliable one is `tr` to delete (`-d`) character code octal 15, aka control-M or `\r` or carriage return:

```
tr -d '\015' < input | sed -e 's/  *$//' -e '/^ *$/d' > output
```

If neither of those works, then you need to show a hex dump or octal dump (`od -c`) of the first two lines of the file, so we can see what we're up against:

```
head -n 2 input | od -c
```

---

Judging from the comments that `sed -i` does not work for you, you are not working on Linux or Mac OS X or BSD — which platform are you working on?  (AIX, Solaris, HP-UX spring to mind as relatively plausible possibilities, but there are plenty of other less plausible ones too.)

You can try the POSIX named character classes such as `sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'`; it will probably work, but is not guaranteed.  You can try it with:

```
echo "Hello World" | sed 's/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*/   /'
```

If it works, there'll be three spaces between the 'Hello' and the 'World'.  If not, you'll probably get an error from `sed`.  That might save you grief over getting tabs typed on the command line.

Comment: If I execute the above command still I have blank lines in my output file.What could be the reason?

Comment: Probably your "blank" lines are not empty, they contains whitespace.  See my answer for a solution to remove lines consisting of _any_ whitespace

Comment: Yes looks like there are white spaces.How do I remove them which are present at the end of the line?

Comment: oh FFS, **noone can answer correctly if you ask the wrong question!**

Answer (score 8):

```
grep . file
```

grep looks at your file line-by-line; the dot `.` matches anything *except* a newline character. The output from grep is therefore all the lines that consist of something other than a single newline.

Comment: You might use `grep '[^[:space:]]' file` in case the "blank" lines contain whitespace.

Comment: Would 19 characters of explanation really have been too much?

Comment: @JoshCaswell It'd just be pointless. It'd be like when you read code that says "i=0" and someone adds a comment "set the variable i to the value zero" because someone sometime told them that adding comments to code is a good idea. In this case either it's glaringly obvious what that grep command does or the OP REALLY needs to read the man page.

Comment: Less pointless than a copy-pasted error message about your post being too short? We have different definitions of "pointless".

Comment: Not less pointless, equally pointless but more effort. In a perfect world the web site simply wouldn't require a minimum number of characters and then we wouldn't have had this fruitless discussion.

Answer (score 7):

with awk

`awk 'NF > 0' filename`

Comment: `awk 'NF'` alone is enough.

Answer (score 3):

To be thorough and remove lines *even* if they include spaces or tabs something like this in perl will do it:

```
cat file.txt | perl -lane "print if /\S/"
```

Of course there are the awk and sed equivalents. Best not to assume the lines are *totally* blank as `^$`  would do.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can sed's `-i` option to edit in-place without using temporary file:

```
 sed -i '/^$/d' file
```

Comment: Then the lines are not "blank" lines. Jonathan Wakely answered how to remove whitespaces too. Doesn't it work?

Comment: Can you describe it clearly how exactly the blank lines are still there?

Comment: My 19th column has whitespaces.So I guess I should remove whitespaces first and then execute any of these commands..

Comment: No. `sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' file` should remove all lines with any whitespace such as <tab>, <space>, <blank line> or any combination of these.

Comment: There's no syntax error in the command. Do you use it *exacty* like in my previous comment? can you copy-paste the exact command you use?

Comment: sed: illegal option -- i
Usage: sed [-n] [-e script] [-f source_file] [file...]

Comment: No. How you use the sed command. Is it like this? `sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' filename` ?

Comment: Yes its the same way as it is mentioned in the answer.

Comment: You cannot avoid a temporary file with `sed -i`, because `sed -i` uses a temporary file.

Comment: Right. At least saving externally moving again is not needed. It seems `-i` option is not supported on OP's system. Though there are working solutions here, he just doesn't seem to get it working!