# Importing PIPE delimited format txt into MySQL via PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, pipe, csv

I am importing some thousands lines of Data from a .txt file containing two columns and the format is as it follows:

```
A8041550408#=86^:|blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla1

blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla2

blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla3

A8041550408#=86^:|blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla1

blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla2
A8041550408#=86^:|blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla1

blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla2

blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla3

blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla4
etc....
```

What I have done so far is create a table with the two fields, but when i try to import the .txt file as a CSV and putting / Columns separated By : | /, I get an error:

```
"Invalid column count in CSV input on line 2."
```

Which is quite obvious since the second line of the .txt file is empty.

Moreover, I have tried importing the file as a CSV using LOAD DATA, and it didn't work as well it has just filled up  the table with random words and phrases from the .txt file .
So my question is : How can I import the data from this file ?

Comment: Do you mean that lines 2, 4, 6, etc are all empty?

Comment: Yes ... and it's not even a pattern as you can see sometimes there are lines sometimes not !

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix your file; in its current state you cannot expect the import module to be able to understand it. First step would be to remove the empty lines: [How to remove blank lines from a Unix file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570489/how-to-remove-blank-lines-from-a-unix-file)