# removing empty lines from a pipe using sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, git-bash

```
$ find ~/AppData/Local/atom/ -name atom.sh -type f | grep -FzZ 'cli/atom.sh' | sed '/^\s*$/d' | cat -n
     1  /c/Users/devuser/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.12.1/resources/cli/atom.sh
     2  /c/Users/devuser/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.12.2/resources/cli/atom.sh
     3
```

I tried a number of [sed/awk-based options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570580/145682) to get rid of the blank line. (`#3` in the output). But I can't quite get it right...

I need to get the last line into a variable...

The below actual command I am working with fails to give an output...

```
 find ~/AppData/Local/atom/ -name atom.sh -type f | grep -FzZ 'cli/atom.sh' | sed '/^$/d' | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Okay, its a dirty way, but a combination of reverse sorting and `head -n 1` temporarily solved the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `-Z` flag of `grep`. It causes `grep` to terminate matched lines with a null character instead of a newline. This won't work well with `sed`, because `sed` processes input line by line, and it expects each line to be terminated by a newline. In your example `grep` doesn't emit any newline characters, so as far as `sed` is concerned, it receives a block of text without a terminating newline, so it processes it as a single line, and so the pattern `/^\s*$/` doesn't match anything.

Furthermore, the `-z` flag would only make sense if the filenames in the output of `find` were terminated by null characters, that is with the `-print0` flag. But you're not using that, so the `-z` flag in `grep` is pointless. And the `-Z` flag is pointless too, because that should be used when the next command in the pipeline expects null-terminated records, which is not your case.

Do like this:

```
find ~/AppData/Local/atom/ -name atom.sh -type f -print0 | grep -zF 'cli/atom.sh' | tr '\0' '\n' | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 9):

Below sed command would remove all the empty lines.

```
sed '/^$/d' file
```

or

Below sed command would remove all the empty lines and also the lines having only spaces.

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' file
```

Add `-i` parameter to do an in-place edit.

```
sed -i '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all `sed`'s support the token `\s` for any whitespace character.

You can use the character class `[[:blank:]]` (for space or tab), or `[[:space:]]` (for any whitespace):

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d'
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
```

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` is for spaces and tabs, so I don't think you need the second sed command.

Comment: @Kenavoz Yes, thats just for the sake of completeness (and conformance with `\s`).